# Lyx and Mendeley bibliography

Tags: lyx, bibliographies, citing

I am absolutely new to Latex, Tex and whatever more there is, so I decided to try Lyx to make my life easier (haven't had much success, though). I am also using Mendeley to manage my bibliography and export a .bib file to be read in Lyx.

The problem is, no matter what style I choose in either Lyx or Mendeley, I get a weird citation/bibliography layout.

The bibliography in the outcome PDF looks like this:

```
|Bokpin(2013)| Bokpin, G. a., 2013. Ownership structure, corporate governance
and bank eciency: an empirical analysis of panel data from the banking
industry in Ghana. Corporate Governance 13 (3), 274287.
URL http://www.emeraldinsight.com/10.1108/CG-05-2010-0041
```

What I don't want is the key to appear in the beggining, ie `[Bokpin(2013)]`. The second problem is that the same key appears where the citation should be in the text, for example:

```
According to |Bokpin(2013|, the same behaviour [...]
```

Where it should be something like this

```
According to Bokpin (2013), the same behaviour [...]
```

or, depending on the chosen style, like this

```
The same behaviour [...] (BOKPIN, 2013)
```

Is there a configuration I should be doing in either Lyx or Mendeley that I not doing correctly (or at all)?

I don't know what other information should be useful so you could help me, so feel free to comment below and I'll provide what is needed.

Thanks,

Bernardo

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://goo.gl/z69vm) Your post was migrated here from [so]. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other (by using the same OpenID), otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question.

Answer (score 3):

You should use BibTeX files generated by Mendeley.   Go to Tools->Options->BibTeX and select where to store your BibTeX files.

In LyX Go to: Insert->Lists->BibTeX Bibliography, click *Add*, and navigate to where your BibTeX  file is stored.

Then again  choose Insert-> Citation.

Comment: Your answer is hardly readable and understandable.

Comment: Sorry, wrote on my phone.

Comment: [This post](https://onhavingwords.wordpress.com/2013/03/19/mendeley-lyx/) explains the process in more details.